# How to Run C code in WebBrowser using PHP

Tags: php, html, c, browser, command-line-arguments

Suggest a method to take input as command-line-arguments from a single text-box in Web-Browser.
These numbers are then added using C code and Display the result again in the Web-Browser.
Suggest, How can I use PHP or HTML to link my C code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done php for a long time now ...

If I understand you well I would do that :

- Your html should send the request (http GET request) with the two numbers to your server (from your form).
- The triggered php script should use the shell_exec command from php to execute a c program.
- The program shall print the sum to the console (http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).
- Then the result string would be sent back to the webbrower

I hope I'm right.

Comment: I understood those steps..but,as i am a beginner,I dont know that level of programming.
It would be helpful if you could elaborate with functions to use to do all those steps in different languages.

Comment: Instead of PHP, can we use CGI ?